# Project build.gradle file won't open, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is the first time I've encountered this issue with Studio. For both the project and app level files, when I double click to open *build.gradle* I get the following problems:

Android Studio 2.3 - File opens, but displays "Loading" indefinitely.

Android Studio 3.0 - File doesn't even open at all. Clicking on them does nothing.

Has anyone else seen this behavior before? And solutions? Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. This plugin was causing it: 'Android Method Count'.
I deleted the plugin, and it worked

Answer (score 1):

delete xxx.iml file, if that still doesn`t work, restart Android studio more.